# Is there any way to load result query in memory?

Tags: java, database, large-data

I have a huge database (2.1 billions row) and I need to perform some calculation to extract some statistical results. To my understanding, it's obvious that it is not wise to perform the calculation directly on this database.

What I'm trying to do now is to load a portion of the table into memory (says 1 million rows). I'm not sure how to load the whole chunk of the data of the ResultSet into memory without iterating row by row.

Any idea?

Comment: `To my understanding, it's obvious that it is not wise to perform the calculation directly on this database.` Depends on the calculation.

Comment: I agree with Jacob: your understanding is wrong. That's exactly what relational DBMS where meant to do.

Answer (score 7):

> it's obvious that it is not wise to perform the calculation directly on this database

On the contrary, it is very likely that doing it in the database is the wisest way to do it. Databases are built precisely to handle huge amounts of data. If you can express your calculation as an SQL query, the database will work out how to execute it efficiently. In general, it will do this far quicker than if you loaded all the data into memory and processed it yourself.

There are some kinds of calculation where this is not the case - graph analyses, for example - but it should be your default approach.

Comment: Totally agree, data manipulation is usually handled better by databases. In most cases precalculating in the database and then querying just the results is the best approach in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have a problem with iterating over the result set? If you want the actual data to be retrieved in larger chunks (e.g. to prevent network roundtrips to the database), you can set the result set's fetch size to hint the JDBC driver to retrieve larger portions of data.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with previous answers that it may be not good to load such amount in memory.
But answering your question, there is class for disconnected representation of `ResultSet`: [`javax.sql.RowSet`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/sql/RowSet.html)

Comment: Disconnected won't solve the problem of all that RAM on the middle tier.

Answer (score 0):

Moving millions of rows from the database to the middle tier, just to do a calculation that could be done on the database, makes no sense to me at all.  You should look into doing this on the database.  Prototype it and see if the data convinces you to drop your prejudice.

Comment: Ok I will be more specific on the data, I have a date field. I need to run some statistics on days of the week and hours of the day. e.g. on monday there are million records etc. I think i can run this stats on smaller portion and on multiple thread. In the end I will aggregate all results together.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is called [OLAP (Online Analytical Processing)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OLAP). Many RDBMS have a rich feature set for such functionality, precisely for calculating stuff, for instance Oracle Analytic Functions. If the calculation cannot be done in a single SQL query, you can write stored procedures doing the job for you.

But please - do not load terabytes of data out of some database just do do some calculations that can be done in the data store directly. Why? You'll use 99% of the time for data-loading and transfer and 1% for calculation.